# ¿Cuál es el objetivo de (are you planning on sharing this bundle acrross multiple application) cuando se esta instalando un Bundle de Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony3

he buscado mucho en la web y no he encontrado mucho verán estoy creando un Bundle en Symfony3 por medio del siguiente comando:

> php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=MiBundle --format=yml

luego de ejecutarlo me indica lo siguiente:
are you planning on sharing this bundle acrross multiple application

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que quiere decir si deseo compartir el módulo o el paquete en múltiples aplicaciones.

Pero deseo saber el objetivo de esto o cuando se debe colocar si y cuando no.

Comment: Existen multitud de bundles que simplifican tareas y que pueden ser usados por cualquier proyecto de Symfony, por ejemplo: http://symfony.com/blog/the-30-most-useful-symfony-bundles-and-making-them-even-better Si tu bundle tiene esa finalidad, deberías responder Sí. Aunque en la mayoría de los casos, los desarrollos son específicos y lo natural será responder NO.

Comment: Gracias por responder Muriano, entonces solo es como una descripción para indicar si servirá para otros proyectos o no. Yo pensaba que si aplicaba si se realizaba otro tipo de configuraciones en el bundle, gracias.

Comment: Creo que la configuración generada varía, pero no te puedo decir en qué manera.

Comment: ha ok gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los bundles compartidos como te dice Muriano están pensados para ser usados en varios proyectos.

La diferencia básica de configuración reside en los namespace, es decir si creo un bundle para generar un blog y tengo pensado compartirlo el namespace será Autor\NombreBundle , ej Iweb\BlogBundle en caso de ser solo para un proyecto sería simplemente NombreBundle ej BlogBundle

La finalidad de esta configuración es para que al agregarle el composer.json y otros ficheros para facilitar la integración dentro de un vendor por ejemplo sea más estandarizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración